# Standard error of a sample

Tags: standard-error

I want to calculate a standard error of a sample. I have a distribution of the IQ of the general population with a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 19. Now I take a random sample of 30 students of Harvard  and find that their mean IQ is 125.

I want to calculate the standard error of the mean. How can I do this? I cannot use $\sigma \over \sqrt{n}$ because I don't have the sd of my sample or?

Comment: You need the sample standard deviation $\hat{\sigma}$ to estimate the standard error.

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought. We don't have that. Is there another way like bootstrapping?

Comment: You can only do bootstrap if you have a sample, which you don't, otherwise you could estimate the SD.

Comment: I also know that the IQ is normal distributed. That's it. That are all information in the question.

Comment: Then you are figuratively screwed.